# Como criar uma div com height em porcentagem?

Tags: html, html5, css3

Boas, pessoal! Tenho uma dúvida. Quando crio uma `div/footer/header` e vou no css editar suas dimensões consigo tranquilamente colocar o `width 100%`, porém o `height` não consigo editar com porcentagem, apenas com px, poderiam me dar uma dica de como fazer isso?

No caso eu deveria colocar o `body` com `height` de 100% para os outros terem uma dimensão de quantos % ocupar?

Evito colocar px pois creio que o site não fica responsivo sem isso, porém caso tenho alguma dica agradeço.
Obrigado desde já!

Answer (score 1):

Se você tentar definir a altura de um contêiner div para 100% da janela do navegador usando a altura da regra de estilo: 100%; não funciona, porque a porcentagem (%) é uma unidade relativa, portanto a altura resultante depende da altura da altura do elemento pai.

Por exemplo, se você considerar o exemplo a seguir, a div .container possui dois elementos pai: o elemento  e o . E todos sabemos que o valor padrão da propriedade height é automático. Portanto, se também definirmos a altura dos elementos  e  como 100%, a altura resultante da div do contêiner se tornará igual à altura de 100% do elemento janela do navegador.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Set DIV Height to 100% Using CSS</title>
<style type="text/css">
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
    }
    .container {
        height: 100%;
        background: #f0e68c;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">The height of this DIV element is equal to the 100% height of its parent element's height.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

O elemento pai deve está com a `position=relative` Dessa forma, os elementos filhos podem estar com o **height** com porcentagem. Lembrando que o elemento pai deve estar com o **height** definido.